# Can the diagonal elements of a precision matrix be 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

I have this confusion that why the diagonal elements of the precision matrix cannot be 0?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: ...what is a precision matrix? Where did you see this?

Comment: @J.M. Inverse of the covariance matrix

Answer (score 2):

The covariance matrix $E[(X-EX)(X-EX)^T]$ is positive-semidefinite, so (assuming it's invertible at all) positive definite, and so its inverse is also positive-definite. The diagonal elements of any positive-definite matrix $M$ are always strictly positive, because they're given by $e^T M e$ where $e = e_1,...,e_n$ runs through the standard basis vectors of $R^n$.